# Gem Loading Error, installed from Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

**Update**:  This gem DOES install with sudo rake gems:install.  The problem is with loading.  For instance, when I run script/console, it throws:

```
no such file to load -- outoftime-noaa ...
```

Even though sudo rake gems:install just installed it.  I'm not sure if this matter, probably does, but it throws this error twice.

-=-=-

I'm looking to provide users with up to date weather information in my Rails application.

I'm looking for something similar to outoftime's NOAA gem (http://github.com/outoftime/noaa/tree/master).

The reason I ask is I'm having a hell of a time getting the gem to work.  If anyone here has a revelation as to what's going on, I'd appreciate the help.

I've added this to my environment config:

```
config.gem "outoftime-noaa", :source => "http://gems.github.com"
```

I've run

```
sudo rake gems:install
```

I get this error

```
no such file to load -- outoftime-noaa
```

I have the other two required gems already installed on my system.  I'm using one of them (geokit) in my app.

I'm using Rails 2.3.2, Ruby 1.8.6 and Rubygems 1.3.1.

Comment: Do you have any other gems as config.gem?

Comment: Yes, and all of them work.  I'm not sold this is a rake gems:install issue.  Jim changed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
config.gem "outoftime-noaa", :lib => "noaa", :source => "http://gems.github.com"
```

Most github gems need the lib specified.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like 'outoftime-noa' is part of Rubygems; `gem search -r outoftime-noa` gives no results.  Have you done: `sudo gem sources --add http://gems.github.com` ?

If so, can you install the gem manually?

Edit: I've never used config.gem (Rails has too many new features to keep track of... ;) ), but it looks like you need to specify non-standard sources, so:

```
 config.gem "outofime-noa", :source => "http://gems.github.com"
```

Does that work?

Comment: I get this:

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

outoftime-noaa (0.2.2)

Comment: Yes, see above.  I've added that line to my environment.rb file.